# Web Part heading colour change

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, style.css

I need to change the heading (background and Font) colour coding of each web part that will add in site. I tried it with SharePoint Color palette. It can only change web part heading.

I guess, I need to change in the Master page that !

does any one have codes, where to change what !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code to change the color of web part header title and the background color of web part header

```
<style>
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText
{
 color:white ! important;
}

.js-webpart-titleCell
{
background-color:blue ! important;
}
</style>
```

**To apply this code for all web part, if you have a publishing site, try the following**

- Create a new CSS file, add the above code > upload it to style library.
- Go to site setting > Look and Feel > Master Page >

[image]

- At Site Master Page Settings > Scroll down till `Alternate CSS URL`
- Check `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:`
- Browse to your CSS file
- Check  `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL`  if you need to apply CSS for all subsites.

[image]

**Output**

[image]

if you don't have publishing site, > take a copy from your current master page > edit the current master page > paste the above code in head section> save and publish the master page as a major version.

Answer (score 2):

if one writes

```
.ms-webpart-titleText.ms-webpart-titleText  {
  color:white ! important;
}
```

One clearly has no clue how CSS Selectors work

The double class Selector was copied from Corev15.css,
it shows that some Microsoft developer ran into trouble styling `.ms-webpart-titleText` elements and increased its **Specificity** by repeating the class Selector so that its style definition would be applied over any **later** defined CSS rule with a single class `.ms-webpart-titleText` Selector.

That Developer did **not** use `!important` to solve the problem because he/she understood what CSS Specificity does.

Applying `!important` is the most brutal way of overloading CSS and destroys any capability of re-styling the element.
If you use this in a real WebDevelopment team you will get some serious flack from real designers.

In this case `!important` is preventing the `.ms-webpart-titleText > a` color from being applied.
**That** is the rule coloring the Title

So use the proper CSS selector:

```
.ms-webpart-titleText > a  {
  color:white;
}
```

when your CSS loads **after** Corev15.css

Or use

```
H2.ms-webpart-titleText > a  {
  color:white;
}
```

when you want your CSS to trump Microsofts **Specificity**
(and be applied no matter when your CSS loads)

- https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: if you need to answer please don't talk about me with this way again, you have the right to answer, but you don't have the right to talk about me, this is not the first time you do that ,  I have only repeat ms-webpart-titleText with wrong and your answer is not completed based on the question request ! so don't care about my answer and provide your answer without any insult!